# Test LDAP connection with sample users

Tags: ldap, sap-commerce-cloud

I don't know much about this topic, is the first time when I need to do this.
I have a platform (an e-commerce website) with the LDAP extension added, I must test to see if LDAP is working.
I understood that I need an active directory…but I really don’t understand or I don’t know how to search to get something that can be useful.
I need some test users to see if LDAP protocol is working... 
Do you have any tutorials or documentation about this? Like, for dummies :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a public test LDAP server detailed at https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

That's not Active Directory, so no good if you have a *specific* requirement to test **Active Directory** LDAP. I doubt you'd find a public Active Directory for testing -- you may be able to use a free trial of Windows Server 2019 (or free trial in MS's Azure cloud) to set up a Windows server on which you [create a AD test domain](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Windows-Server-2019-Step-4c0a3678/file/204046/1/Windows%20Server%202019-Step%20by%20Step%20Installation%20of%20Domain%20Controller.pdf).

Comment: Thank you LisaJ. I’ll follow your advice and set up a Windows server.

Comment: I'm having issue understanding the difference between LDAP server and Active Directory LDAP? What will be the specific requirements for the latter?

Comment: So, it's kind of like the difference between a SQL server and a MariaDB server -- there are lots of LDAP servers out there (OpenLDAP, OpenJD, Oracle Unified Directory, Tivoli Directory Server). LDAP is a way of interacting with a directory server -- kind of like SQL is a way of interacting with a database server.

Comment: Active Directory is Microsoft's directory server. It's got roots in the Windows NT domain architecture. Usually I've encountered it in companies with a significant Windows workstation base -- computers "join the domain" and then users can log onto their workstations without having an account specifically created on the computer. Since the company has already paid for & maintains the directory servers, they then use AD for any LDAP-authenticated application.

Comment: As to what you need to run it -- simplest approach is using one of the Windows eval VHDs (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016/) and follow instructions for a basic AD installation (e.g. https://ittutorials.net/microsoft/windows-server-2016/setting-up-active-directory-ad-in-windows-server-2016/)